# Default Dict / Sort by min

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

and thank you in advance for your help. I have this code so far :

```
with open("clean_result.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as 
new_data:
reader = csv.reader(new_data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    if row:
        columns = [row[0], row[1]]
        init_dict.append(columns)

for ean, price in init_dict:
    result[ean].append(price)
```

And then I get the min value for each price with this line :

```
maxitems = {ean : min(result[ean]) for ean in result}
```

Current Output : {'8714789828558': '5,51', '3326100000182': '15,00', '3286010016683': '3,93' (...) }

---

What I would like to is add row[2] and get additionnal info, but only for the minimum price value.

Desired Output : {'8714789828558': '5,51', 'A', '3326100000182': '15,00', 'B' '3286010016683': '3,93', 'C' (...) }

I tried this :

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        columns = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
        init_dict.append(columns)

for ean, price, desc in init_dict:
       result[ean].append(price)
       result[ean].append(desc)

maxitems = {ean : min(result[ean]) for ean in result}
```

But Output is like this. Half data are missing :

{'8714789828558': 'A', '3326100000182': 'B' '3286010016683': 'C' (...) }

I probably misunderstand something so please any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for row in reader:
    if row:
        result[row[0]].append((row[1], row[2]))

minitems = {ean : min(prices, key = itemgetter(0)) for ean, prices in result.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thank you khachik, i just tried your solution and i had this output :
    minitems = {ean: min(prices, key=itemgetter(0)) for ean, prices in result}
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I succeed finally with this line :
minitems = {ean: min(result[ean], key=itemgetter(1)) for ean in result}

! Thannk you for having me on the track !

Comment: @Greenseed the code assumed `result` is a defaultdict. Fixed the value error as well.